# Force Inbound Connections to IPV6 only

Tags: bitcoind, network

Is it possible to restrict all connections to an IPV6 address?

I've set

```
onlynet=ipv6
bind=::
```

But it seems that nodes are still attempting to connect to an IPV4 address (in addition to the IPV6 address).  Is there any way to prevent this?  I am seeing discover and addlocal both being set to the IPV6 address on startup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`onlynet` only affects outbound connections.

If you only want inbound IPv4 connections (why?), you'll need to either:

- Patch Bitcoin Core to bind to IPv6 addresses in IPV6_V6ONLY mode (see `CConnman::BindListenPort` in src/net.cpp)
- Use some firewall rule on your system to prevent incoming IPv4 connections to it
- Make sure you only have a publicly-reachable IPv6 address

Comment: I am only looking for IPv6 connections.  I don't really want my IPv4 address being leaked.

Comment: Is this still true and we need to patch Bitcoin Core for using this option?